# Does a iOS post request has to look same as what rest api expects?

Tags: ios, rest, post

I have to send a JSON file that I collect on my iOS to my backend team. The JSON looks something like:

```
{
  "samples" : [
    {
      "acw" : 11,
      "e_reserved" : 0,
      "acc" : 28,
      "cheat_rate" : 16,
   }
  ]
}
```

I am making a post request to backend at:

```
http://make-post.com/api/post-activities
```

The backend expects the JSON as:

```
 /api/post-activities/
 Request Body
 The request body should be a "application/json" encoded object, 
 containing the following items.

 Parameter      Description
 name   
 time_stamp 
 duration
```

We do not collect all these data ourselves but backend has to process the data we supply and get those info.

What I tried first was to put all these data in an online storage and create a request as:

```
 Request: {“pod_id”:“F11”,“type”:“Normal Activity”,“time_stamp”:“2019-04-17T22:29:35.147Z”,“url”:“https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/mybucket-test\/myid@gmail.com\/2019-04-17\/d9335.json”}
```

But when I send request like this, I get Status Code 400 error.

So my next idea was to pass the whole JSON I collect to them. Upon doing that, they can get the data and see it in there database even though I get 500 error. Does it mean it is not really working?

Comment: yes, your post request has to look the same as the API expects. The OS making the request is of zero interest here. The API defines how to talk to it, you have to follow that, simple as that.

Comment: I’m not seeing _any_ correlation between your JSON for `"samples"`, the list of fields that the documentation says it’s looking for, and the JSON at the end of your question. But, yes, as a general rule, you have to provide JSON with the fields they say are required. The whitespace and order of the properties doesn’t matter, but the general structure and required keys does. (By the way, I assume your request isn’t really using smart-quotes like your question above does. The `"` is what JSON expects, not `“` or `”`.)

Comment: Please take a look at very similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754465/json-request-through-ios-and-request-encode-in-rest-web/55756565#55756565

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear to me, The learnings I have learnt you have some data that you want to pass to backend, and the backend sends 400 as you are not meeting his desire.

Suppose you have three variables to pass , let `name`,`time_stamp`, `duration`.

All you need to do in Swift, use `Codable` protocol.

```
class postJSON : Codable {
   var name : String?
   var time_stamp :  String? // it may be Int64 according to backend what accept
   var duration : String? // it may be Int64 according to backend what accept
}
```

While making a post request just do

```
let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(postJSON)
```